# Cannot load such file -- action_controller/request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rack

I am trying to setup my Rails app (which has been running great on a Debian server) on my new Macbook Air running OS X 10.8.

I started by installing homebrew and rvm, I have installed ruby 1.9.3 using rvm and rails using `gem install rails`. So far it works great. I then downloaded my rails app from my svn repo and ran `rails new myapp` which added the extra files which are not version controlled (such as database config etc). Bundle install ran great.

But when I try to fire up the server I get this:

```
$ rails server
/Users/ephracis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require': cannot load such file -- action_controller/request (LoadError)
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/oauth-0.4.7/lib/oauth/request_proxy/action_controller_request.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/oauth-plugin-0.4.1/lib/oauth-plugin.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/ephracis/Development/Stoffi/Code/branches/features/rails4/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `require'
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I am running rails 4.0 and my Gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier',     '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'devise', :git => "https://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git"
gem 'hanna-nouveau'
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2"
gem "omniauth-lastfm"
gem "omniauth-linkedin"
gem "omniauth-myspace"
gem "omniauth-soundcloud"
gem "omniauth-twitter"
gem "omniauth-vimeo"
gem "omniauth-vkontakte"
gem "omniauth-weibo-oauth2"
gem "omniauth-windowslive"
gem "omniauth-yahoo"
gem "omniauth-yandex"
gem "omniauth-youtube"
gem "omniauth", '>= 1.1.4'
gem 'geoip'
gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails'
gem "oauth-plugin", ">= 0.4.0.pre1"
gem "juggernaut"
gem "i18n_routing"
gem "will_paginate"
gem "wikipedia-client"
gem "mediacloth"
gem "wikicloth"
gem "deep_merge"
gem "htmlentities"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you do bundle install?

Comment: Of course I did, it is part of `rails new`.

Comment: @Debadatt: I have all the latest versions and this is rails 4 and not rails 3. Should I still switch to the rails 3 branch and how do I do that? Is it something like `gem 'oauth-plugin', github: ???`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue resolved look at https://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin/pull/140

You can look at some other rails 4 specific fixes